# Link to a django static file doesnt work

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In my dev. environment there is a /static/ folder, which atm. stores some images for the web-site.

1. My INSTALLED_APPS variable in *settings.py* does contain the 
   **django.contrib.staticfiles** app and

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
2. My **urlpatterns** variable  in *urls.py* has this

   urlpatterns+= static(settings.STATIC_URL,
    document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
3. Finally, in my template.html file i'm iterating through my *cardset* objects and am trying to provide an image for each object like this

   ```
   <img src=" {{STATIC_URL}}/images/{{cardset.image}}" alt="{{ cardset.name }}" class="bn"/>
   ```

Now, the problem is:

a.) the {{STATIC_URL}} resolves as an empty string.

b.) i think i cannot use the **static** tag here because the variable {{cardset.image}} would not work well inside of the django tamplate *{% ... %}* with the **static** tag.

Could you please advice on what I should try doing here?

Comment: settings.STATIC_ROOT is empty?

Comment: @EchoUATeam yes. Should it not be?

Comment: What is `static.image`? is it an ImageField? If so you don't need STATIC_URL at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman atm cardset.image is a string. I sort of know that ImageField is a right way to do, but i'm trying to understand how the things work with the STATIC_URL. Should i jump to ImageField straight away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you can still use the `static` tag. To build your string without using an image field, your link just needs tweaking slightly:

```
<img src="{% static "images/" %}{{cardset.image}}" alt="{{ cardset.name }}" class="bn"/>
```

which should render in html correctly. Depending what your `{{cardset.image}}` looks like you may be able to get rid of the `images/` part in the middle.

Remember you also need to include `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of your template.

Comment: Yay! That worked thanks! One question. This template we are talking about extends another base.html template. The base.html template does have the {% load staticfiles %} thing. Why do i need to specify it one more time on top of the template we are talking about? :)

Comment: No problem! If you already have `{% load staticfiles %}` in your base.html there is no need to add it again, I mentioned it in just in case :)

Comment: Now, that's weird, because without the {% load staticfiles %} on top of the template it won't work. It says: "Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'". My exact hierarchy is base.html -> catalog.html -> template_we_are_talking_about.html. Do you reckon it might not be working because of the hierarchy depth?

Comment: Yes that's weird I get the same error too, and it can't be down to the hierarchy depth because I tried it with a depth of 2... It doesn't mention any problems with this in the docs, so I guess you may have to repeat the `{% load staticfiles %}`, although I'm not sure if this is best practice

Answer (score 0):

Since `cardset.image` is a string, your assumption b is false; tags work perfectly well with variables:

```
 {% static cardset.image %}
```

(The reason `{{ STATIC_URL }}` wasn't working was presumably because you haven't passed it to the template; it's not present automatically, it's just a standard template variable.)

Comment: Thanks first of all!! Quick question: How do i add the '/images/' part of the string into the template?